# Excluding database objects from a DacPac database deployment?

Tags: sql-server, ssdt, visual-studio

As I understand it, a sql server DacPac (visual studio data-tier app) applies to the entire database that it's deployed in. However, for my particular database, I have some tables and stored procs that I want to always remain unchanged in one environment, regardless of the dacpac's current state.

I've been reading about partial/composite database projects, but I'm not sure if/how this can be done with DacPac, or if that is even the solution I'm really looking for. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a DACPAC, you might find generating database scripts more flexible for your needs if you want to exclude specific entities. Here's a good walkthrough on how to do it: [Methods to script SQL Server database objects](https://www.sqlshack.com/methods-to-script-sql-server-database-objects/)